# Everything redirecting to subdomain redirect htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have the following code:

```
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias *.test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
Options All -Indexes
FileETag none
ServerSignature Off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.test\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.test\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /%1.php?o=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

On my old server I had this in a .htaccess file (minus the documentroot part) and it worked fine doing this:

```
sub.test.com -> test.com/sub.php
```

It still does this correctly, but now that I have moved it into the sites-available config file,  if I try to access a file, it breaks and uses that same rule as the file to get:

```
sub.test.com/file.css -> test.com/sub.php
```

Is there a way to keep it from doing this? (I tried doing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and such but it didn't seem to care much about that rule).
Thanks

Comment: Pattern `^$` cannot match `file.css`. Do you have more rules?

Comment: @anubhava I'll add all the rules incase one of them is conflicting somehow

Comment: @anubhava I added it. Its odd that its just not working simply because I moved it into the apache config folder rather than using a .htaccess file because it was definitely working before.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Apache config try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.test\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1.php [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.test\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/?$ /%1.php?o=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Apache config matches a leading slash in `RewriteRule` unlike htaccess

Comment: That still seems to be doing the same thing, all files just automatically match the subdomain rewrite and end up downloading the php file specified by it.

Comment: For testing purpose can you comment out `RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/?$ /%1.php?o=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` rule and see if that changes behavior.

Comment: Okay that causes all the files to load correctly, but now all the subdomains just load the page index.php (by the way that part of it just does `sub.test.com/path/` to `test.com/sub.php?o=path` or something like that, it might have the trailing slash in the query too)